# How can I get the null deviance of a glmer() model?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Is there a way to get the null deviance and df for a generalized linear mixed model fit with glmer()? Is there a reason that this is not included in the summary() output, the way that it is with a glm() object?

Comment: @Dion, those comments are about deviance (i.e. -2*logLik either on its own or relative to a saturated model), not about the null deviance.

Comment: Somehow my comment is now gone. Anyway, taking a closer look, I see that this [post](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/375#issuecomment-214494445) indeed was not about null deviance, thanks for noting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the null deviance by re-fitting the model with an intercept term only, e.g.

```r
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
                   data = cbpp, family = binomial)
gm0 <- update(gm1, . ~ 1 + (1|herd))
deviance(gm1)  ## 73.47
deviance(gm0)  ## 92.42 (null deviance)
```

- I'm not sure what you mean by the "null df" for the GLMM; the 'denominator degree of freedom' measure of effective sample size that works perfectly for balanced ANOVAs and questionably for linear mixed models [via inclusion/exclusion, Satterthwaite, Kenward-Roger, etc.] is hard to define for GLMMs.
- I can think of a couple of reasons that `lme4` doesn't automatically do this computation for you:

  - it could be an expensive re-fit (even for GLMs it does require refitting the model, see [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/library/stats/R/glm.R#L104-L115) for the code in `glm` that does it)
  - it's less obvious for GLMMs what the appropriate null model for comparison is. Do you remove both random and fixed effects and reduce the model to a GLM? Do you keep all of the random effects, or only intercept-level random effects, or some other mixture depending on the context of the question? Making the user do it themselves forces them to make this choice.

(That said, I don't believe that omitting the null deviance was an explicit choice.)

If you do choose to discard all of the random effects (i.e. comparing to `deviance(glm(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period, data =cbpp, family = binomial))` in the example above, you should be able to do a meaningful comparison with a `glmer` fit, but there are some subtleties: you might want to read the section on *Deviance and log-likelihood of GLMMs* in `?deviance.merMod`.

Comment: That's very helpful - thanks for your response!